# What if i put the same publisher Id in 10 apps(for example)?

Tags: android, admob

Like i said, what happend if i put the same Publisher ID(from one app) in for example 10 more? I mean, is not important the quantity, but is to be clear that i will put the publisher id from app A, in app B, C, D. I still get the ads/impressions/clicks BUT in admob will show like all comes from app A right?
And it is allowed?
Thanks

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/gNZ6xD0IXw8/x6axuJEmXK8J

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. It's about AdMob's terms and services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know why you want to do that. Having 10 different ad unit id's might be useful.
First of all, getting proper reporting of 10 different apps will let you know which app out of 10 is getting the most impressions/revenue which is good for business. And also, you can analyse, how other apps are performing individually.

Secondly, by 10 different ad unit ID's, for example some month, a particular type of app is advertising at higher eCPM ( which is related to one of your app in that category), so you will get the benefit of higher eCPM. Similarly in the next month, the trend might change to another category ( which maybe similar to another app of yours) giving you the maximum of two months.